# Overloading opertator=() in rooted binary tree template class

Tags: c++, algorithm, operator-overloading, binary-tree, graph-traversal

I am writing a template class called `RootedBinaryTree`, which has a linked-list-like structure, whose elements are of type `Node`, which is a struct I have defined in the header file below. Each node in the binary tree has a `parent Node *` and can either have a `leftChild Node *` and a `rightChild Node *` or no children. (For example: if you were to draw a rooted binary tree, it should look something like this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/CompleteBinaryTree_1000.gif).

A rooted binary tree has two members: `root` and `currentPosition` which are of type node. 
When I overload `operator=()` I have to do something like `currentPosition = RHS.currentPosition;` (which is what I have written there currently). I know this is incorrect, and that what I need to do is find the node in the `*this` tree that corresponds to the `currentPosition Node *` in the `RHS` tree.

My question is: what is a good algorithm to traverse the RHS tree to find its `currentPosition Node *` and find the corresponding `Node` in the invoking tree?

My idea is to create an empty string and traverse `RHS` with some sort of depth first search algorithm starting from the root down until I find currentPosition, and keep track of the path I took to get there by appending a 0 to the end of the string if I went down the tree to the left, or a 1 if I went down the tree to the right, and then using that string to traverse the `*this` tree, which should bring me to the corresponding `Node`. However, I know there must be a better way to do it (partially from intuition, partially because my instructor told me there is a better way haha).

Here are the relevant files:

RootedBinaryTree.h

```
#ifndef ROOTEDBINARYTREE_H
#define ROOTEDBINARYTREE_H 

template <class T>
class RootedBinaryTree
{
private:
    template <class T>
    struct Node
    {
        T nodeData;
        Node<T> * parent; 
        Node<T> * leftChild; 
        Node<T> * rightChild; 

        Node<T>::Node()
        {
            parent = leftChild = rightChild = 0L; 
        }
    }; 
    Node<T> * root;
    Node<T> * currentPosition; 

    void copySubtree(Node<T> * & target, Node<T> * const & original);
    void deleteSubtree(Node<T> * n); 

public:
    RootedBinaryTree(const T & rootData);
    RootedBinaryTree(const RootedBinaryTree<T> & original);
    ~RootedBinaryTree(); 
    void toRoot();
    bool moveLeft();
    bool moveRight();
    bool moveUp(); 
    T getData() const {return currentPosition->nodeData;}; 
    RootedBinaryTree<T> & operator=(const RootedBinaryTree<T> & RHS);
    void combineTrees(const RootedBinaryTree<T> & leftTree, const RootedBinaryTree<T> & rightTree);
    void setNodeData(const T & nodeData); 
};

#endif
```

RootedBinaryTree.cpp

```
#ifndef ROOTEDBINARYTREE_CPP
#define ROOTEDBINARYTREE_CPP

#include "RootedBinaryTree.h"

template<class T>
void RootedBinaryTree<T>::copySubtree(Node<T> * & target, Node<T> * const & original) 
{// Assumes that target's leftChild = rightChild = 0L. I.e. target is a leaf. 
    target = new Node<T>; 
    if(original->leftChild != 0L)
    {
        target->leftChild->parent = target;
        copySubtree(target->leftChild, original->leftChild); 
    } 
    else
    { 
        target->leftChild = 0L; 
    }
    // ^^^ copy targets left (and right) children to originals
    if(original->rightChild != 0L) 
    {
        target->rightChild->parent = target;
        copySubtree(target->rightChild, original->rightChild);
    }
    else
    {
        target->rightChild = 0L; 
    }
    target->nodeData = original->nodeData;
}

template <class T> 
void RootedBinaryTree<T>::deleteSubtree(Node<T> * n)                                                // Done 
{// Assumes that n is a valid node. 
    if(n->leftChild != 0L) deleteSubtree(n->leftChild);                                             // Delete all nodes in left subtree
    if(n->rightChild != 0L) deleteSubtree(n->rightChild);                                           // Delete all nodes in right subtree 
    delete n; 
}

template <class T>
RootedBinaryTree<T>::RootedBinaryTree(const T & rootData)                                           // Done
{
    root = new Node <T>;                                                                            // Roots parent = leftChild = rightChild = 0L  
    root->nodeData = rootData; 
    currentPosition = root; 
}

template <class T>
RootedBinaryTree<T>::RootedBinaryTree(const RootedBinaryTree<T> & original)                         // done 
{
    root = currentPosition = new Node<T>; 
    *this = original; 
}

template <class T>
RootedBinaryTree<T>::~RootedBinaryTree()                                                            // done
{
    deleteSubtree(root);                                                                            // root will be valid because of our constructor and other methods
    root = currentPosition = 0L;    
}

template <class T>
void RootedBinaryTree<T>::toRoot()                                                                  // Done
{
    currentPosition = root; 
}

template <class T>
bool RootedBinaryTree<T>::moveUp()                                                                  // Done
{
    if(currentPosition->parent == 0L) return false;                                                 // If we are at the root of the tree, we cannot move up it. 
    currentPosition = currentPosition->parent; 
    return true; 
}

template <class T>
bool RootedBinaryTree<T>::moveLeft()                                                                // Done 
{
    if(currentPosition->leftChild == 0L) return false; 
    currentPosition = currentPosition->leftChild; 
    return true; 
}

template <class T>
bool RootedBinaryTree<T>::moveRight()                                                               // Done 
{
    if(currentPosition->rightChild == 0L) return false; 
    currentPosition = currentPosition->rightChild;
    return true; 
}

template <class T>
RootedBinaryTree<T> & RootedBinaryTree<T>::operator=(const RootedBinaryTree<T> & RHS)
{
    if(&RHS == this)
    {
        return *this; 
    }
    this->~RootedBinaryTree();  
    copySubtree(root, RHS.root); 
    currentPosition = RHS.currentPosition; // This is wrong. 

    return *this; 
}

template <class T>
void RootedBinaryTree<T>::combineTrees(const RootedBinaryTree<T> & leftTree, const RootedBinaryTree<T> & rightTree)
{ // Copies leftTree into root's left tree and rightTree into root's right tree.
    if(this == &leftTree || this == &rightTree)
    {
        throw "A rooted binary tree cannot be combined with itself."; 
    }
    if(root->leftChild != 0L) deleteSubtree(root->leftChild);
    if(root->rightChild != 0L) deleteSubtree(root->rightChild);
    copySubtree(root->leftChild, leftTree.root);
    copySubtree(root->rightChild, rightTree.root);
}

template <class T>
void RootedBinaryTree<T>::setNodeData(const T & nodeData)
{
    currentPosition->nodeData = nodeData; 
}

#endif
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers this! Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your question. Are you trying to make a deep copy (that is, copy all of the nodes in one tree)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just so you know, your `copySubtree` causes **undefined behavior**.

Comment: What kind of behavior do you mean?

Comment: "Undefined Behavior" is a technical term in computer science. It means that you're going off the map, performing an operation whose outcome is not specified by the language standards. *Anything can happen.* Specifically, you're doing `target->leftChild->parent = target;` when `target->leftChild` is null. Dereferencing a null pointer causes undefined behavior; maybe just a segmentation fault, but it might work as intended sometimes, it might cause memory corruption and keep running, it might create a cycle in a tree that would hang your program, it might crash your OS.

Comment: Oh, right. I see what you mean. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it by implementing a private method `getPath()` that returns a list of moves (left or right) that leads from the `root` to `currentPosition`:

```
template <class T>
list<bool> RootedBinaryTree<T>::getPath() const
{
  list<bool> path;

  Node<T> *p1=currentPosition;
  Node<T> *p2 = p1->parent;

  while(p2 != 0L)
    {
      if(p2->leftChild==p1)
        path.push_front(true);
      else
        path.push_front(false); // yes, I know this can be done more concisely; I'm going for clarity                   
      p1=p2;
      p2=p1->parent;
    }
  return(path);
}
```

Call this method on the other tree, get the path, then follow that path in this tree:

```
template <class T>
void RootedBinaryTree<T>::followPath(list<bool> path)
{
  currentPosition = root;

  for(list<bool>::const_iterator itr=path.begin(); itr !=path.end() ; ++itr)
    if(*itr)
      moveLeft();
    else
      moveRight();
}
```